# Is it possible to dynamically import modules based on an existing service?

Tags: angular

I have an existing service, which is a collection of services, registered with an opaque token of the name `EFFECTS`. Essentially the service is just an array of child services which share the same interface.

For each of the `EFFECTS` services I would like to import the `EffectsModule` into the `AppModule` and inject each service into the `EffectsModule.run()` method.

Please see below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { Account, User } from './models';
import { AccountEffects, UserEffects } from './effects';
import { ApiService } from '../core/services/api.service';
import { EFFECTS } from './tokens';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    { 
      // HOW??
      useFactory: (effects) => effects.map(effect => EffectsModule.run(effect)), 
      deps: [EFFECTS],
    }
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: EFFECTS,
      useClass: UserEffects,
      useFactory: (Actions, ApiService) => new AccountEffects(Actions, ApiService, Account),
      multi: true,
      deps: [Actions, ApiService]
    },
    {
      provide: EFFECTS,
      useClass: UserEffects,
      useFactory: (Actions, ApiService) => new UserEffects(Actions, ApiService, User),
      multi: true,
      deps: [Actions, ApiService]
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: No, it is not possible. This is obviously XY problem, but the solution may vary. In the first place this is a problem specific to `@ngrx/effects` and the pattterns that are inherent to it. I would suggest to re-ask the question with more details and and ngrx specificity, because it doesn't make much sense for the devs who aren't ngrx/redux adepts.

Comment: Disagree. It's an architecture pattern that other developers may run into as the ecosystem expands.

Comment: This is a limitation imposed by the way the framework works. In other scenarios devs aren't limited with this *import modules based on an existing service* requirement; this way shouldn't be normally taken because it leads to dead end.